# How can I use this code to play more sounds?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

```
   //Action to play Audio//
 -(IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
[self.loopPlayer play];
}

 //Action to stop Audio//
-(IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender {
if (self.loopPlayer.isPlaying) {
    [self.loopPlayer stop];
    self.loopPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    self.loopPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
    [self.loopPlayer prepareToPlay];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//Code that gets audio file "trap synth"//
NSURL* audioFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"trapsynth" withExtension:@"wav"];
self.loopPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:nil];

}
```

This is the code i'm using with one button to play the sound when the button is tapped and stop the sound when the button is released. How would I go about adding more sounds to more buttons? I want to have more buttons that play and stop different sounds just like this.

```
property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *loopPlayer;
```

This code is also in my ViewController.h file

Comment: In interface builder (attributes inspector) scroll down until you see the View heading and under that is tag attribute. IBOutlets and IBActions are completely different things.

Comment: I'm getting this warning Unused variable 'audioFileURL2'. Also I set the Id for the first sound button to 1 and the other one to 2. Both buttons however play the same sound.

Comment: Also I don't have any IBOutlet's. Just IBAction's.

Comment: simple--to play more sound you need more avaudioplayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok although the answer provided by Miro is on the write track the code example given has issues.

Should be this in viewDidLoad -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL* audioFileURL1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"trapsynth" withExtension:@"wav"];
    self.loopPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL1 error:nil];

   NSURL* audioFileURL2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"other_audio_file" withExtension:@"wav"];
    self.loopPlayer2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL2 error:nil];
}
```

also stopAudio: method should be this

```
-(IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender {
    if (self.loopPlayer1.isPlaying && (sender.tag == 1)) {
        [self.loopPlayer1 stop];
        self.loopPlayer1.currentTime = 0;
        self.loopPlayer1.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [self.loopPlayer1 prepareToPlay];
    }
    if (self.loopPlayer2.isPlaying && (sender.tag == 2)) {
        [self.loopPlayer2 stop];
        self.loopPlayer2.currentTime = 0;
        self.loopPlayer2.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [self.loopPlayer2 prepareToPlay];
    }
}
```

And finally for playAudio:

```
-(IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    if([sender tag] == 1){
        [self.loopPlayer1 play];
    }
    if([sender tag] == 2){
        [self.loopPlayer2 play];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Each button is playing a different sound now. However when I click both buttons at the same time only one sound plays. Is there a way where I can have both playing at the same time when both are clicked?

Comment: And also still maintain the functionality of the sounds stopping when the buttons are no longer touched.

Comment: Yes you can have more than one player playing at once. It may be better to have separate IBActions for each button to play the audio sample. Have a read of AVAudioPlayer class reference and also core audio programming guide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play different sounds at the same time you should look into creating separate AVAudioPlayers - if you create a different one for each sound, then you can easily control (play/stop) each of them separately with a specific button.

Comment: I understand that however I need to know how to duplicate the code under - (void)viewDidLoad to get each different sound.

Answer (score 0):

On the simplest level, you could do something like this, which allows you to use the same button handlers for all your audio.  The playAudio checks the tag of the Play button you press (be sure to set the tag value in IB, to 1,2,etc). There really only need be one Stop button.

You could enhance this in many ways, like attempting to reuse the AVAudioPlayer somehow, and loading the audio on the fly instead of all at the beginning.  Or storing your audio file info in an array, creating an array of AVAudioPlayers for management, etc. But this is a start.

```
-(IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender {
    // first, stop any already playing audio
    [self stopAudio:sender];

    if([sender tag] == 1){
        [self.loopPlayer1 play];
    } else if([sender tag] == 2){
        [self.loopPlayer2 play];
    }
}

-(IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender {
    if (self.loopPlayer1.isPlaying) {
        [self.loopPlayer1 stop];
        self.loopPlayer1.currentTime = 0;
        self.loopPlayer1.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [self.loopPlayer1 prepareToPlay];
    } else if (self.loopPlayer2.isPlaying) {
        [self.loopPlayer2 stop];
        self.loopPlayer2.currentTime = 0;
        self.loopPlayer2.numberOfLoops = -1;
        [self.loopPlayer2 prepareToPlay];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL* audioFileURL1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"trapsynth" withExtension:@"wav"];
    self.loopPlayer1 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:nil];

   NSURL* audioFileURL2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"trapsynth" withExtension:@"wav"];
    self.loopPlayer2 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioFileURL error:nil];
}
```

AND, in the .h file;

```
property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *loopPlayer1;
property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *loopPlayer2;
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need new IBAction's for each sound so that I connect them to the new buttons? I'm new to all of this so I appreciate your help.

Comment: In Interface Builder you would create a new start button for each sound.  Name it with a title, and add the numeric tag like your code has.  Then link it to the single playAudio handler in IB.  Multiple buttons can use a single IBAction function.

Comment: Alright i'm using images for my buttons without any titles. Would this be an issue? Also what would the numeric tag be? Once again I appreciate you understanding.

Comment: Images are fine.  The numeric tag is just a label you assign to be able to identify which button was pressed when they all go to the same button handler.  See the button handler code to see how it checks for 1, 2, etc.  Those would be the tag you assign to the button in IB.

Comment: Where exactly is the button handler code? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: -(IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender,  is your button handler.

Comment: The conditionals in the stopAudio: method will currently stop the first player that it finds playing. Replace (self.loopPlayer1.isPlaying) with  (self.loopPlayer1.isPlaying && sender.tag ==1) etc

Comment: Alright I added all of this code into my project however i'm still confused as to how to get a different button play the second audio file.

Comment: set the second buttons tag property to 2. This can be set in interface builder from the inspector.

Comment: How do I do that? I'm sorry for being complicated.

Comment: If you have IBOutlets to your buttons, set in code like this in viewDidLoad - yourButton.tag = 2; Otherwise select button in interface builder and on the same panel where you set the buttons title, image etc will be a tag attribute that can be set there.

Comment: The only IBOutlets for my buttons are the -(IBAction)playAudio:(id)sender and -(IBAction)stopAudio:(id)sender. I also can't seem to find the area where you say you can set the tag attribute.